# Как подружить grunt-typescript и requirejs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, grunt, requirejs

Есть следующая проблема: я использую *requirejs* для *AMD*, при этом попытался использовать *typescript* и поставил *grunt-typescript*. Вот отрывок из *Gruntfile.js*:

```
typescript: {
        base: {
            src: ['design/default/ts/*.ts'],
            dest: 'design/default/ts-js',
            options: {
                target: 'es5',
                module: 'amd'
            }
        }
    }
```

Все файлы *typescript* лежат в *design/default/ts*, а компилируются в *design/default/ts-js* и из-за этого возникает следующая проблема:
*design/default/ts/users.ts*

```
import {User} from '../ts/user';

console.log(new User());
```

*design/default/ts-js/users.js*

```
    define(["require", "exports", '../ts/user'], function (require, exports, user_1) {
    console.log(new user_1.User());
});
```

В этом файле и проблема, `["require", "exports", **'../ts/user**']`. *Requirejs* выдает ошибки когда пытаюсь подключить `require(['../ts-js/users'])`:

> require.js:5 GET
>   http://simpla.loc/design/default/ts/user.js?1479310639262
>
> require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "../ts/user", needed by:
>   ../ts-js/users(…)